# Вызов модального окна с разных кнопок в цикле. twig

Tags: javascript, button, for, twig

Работаю в twig. Есть цикл в цикле

```
{% for year in years %}
<tr>
                <td>
                    {{ year }}
                </td>
                {% for month in months %}
                <td>
                        <button class="btn_modal_window">
                            {# какие-то данные #}
                        </button>

                </td>
                {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

есть самое простое модальное окно. В нём я хочу выводить какие-то данные из цикла

```
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal_content">
                <span class="close_modal_window">&times;</span>
                {# например month.id year.id #}
            </div>
        </div>
```

script

```
                $('.btn_modal_window').on('click',function (){
                    $('.modal').css("display","block");
                })
                $('.close_modal_window').on('click', function (){
                    $('.modal').css("display","none");
                })
```

css

```
        .modal{
            display: none;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .modal_content{
            margin: 300px auto;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 20%;
        }
        .close_modal_window{
            color: #000;
            float: right;
            font-size: 30px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

И теперь к самой проблеме. Мне нужно при нажатии кнопки открывать модальное окно с данными, которые находятся в цикле. Как я понял, если хранить само модальное окно в цикле, то при нажатии на любую кнопку будут открываться абсолютно все модальные окна, но если вынести модальное окно за цикл, то окно будет открываться одно. Однако я не понимаю как тогда использовать данные из цикла. Есть какие-нибудь идеи как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <button class="btn_modal_window" data-example="{{ month.id }}>
                            {# какие-то данные #}
                        </button>
```

в самом модальном окне созадл див

```
 <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal_content">
                <span class="close_modal_window">&times;</span>
                <div id="example"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

и в скрипте уже изменяю данные

```
$('.btn_modal_window').on('click',function (){
                    $('.modal').css("display","block");
                    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = $(this).data('example');

                })
```